# JAXB marshall ignore interfaces

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to marshall a class with an interface in it. I got an error saying "JAXB can't handle interfaces.". I've seen several solutions for handling the interfaces, but I think my case is slightly different, because I'm not going to use the data in that interface in the xml. So is there any way to ignore the interface or something like that?

Also, the class (Comment) is got from a library, I don't think I can change the annotation.

```
Comment newComment = event.getComment(); 

// Marshalling
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(newComment.getClass());// error occurs
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

marshaller.marshal(newComment, writer);
```

Comment: Show us an example code fragment, please.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete information

Comment: I meant show us the classes and interfaces that are causing JAXB problems. The actual marshalling logic isn't important.

Comment: After talking with my colleague, we decided to generate xml directly using DOM or SAX, because our data is in a small scale. So, I think this problem is resolved. Thanks for your concern, Sir.

Comment: I still have this problem - I want just added some @XMLElements for the getters I want to be converted to XML. Sadly there are some fields/getters which have a MutlipartFile Interface (Spring). I'd still love to ignore these so JAXB can move on working this out. Any ideas?